# Difference between $(".class:first") and $(".class")[0]

Tags: jquery

I need to use `hasClass()` function one by one on array of elements that I am fetching through `$(".class")`. However it is giving me an error:

> hasClass is not a function

The above method is available in `$(".class:first")`. Is there in any difference in objects returned by both ways? And also, How can we check `hasClass` for each element in an array. Below is the sample code.

```
$(".class").each(function(){
    if (this.hasClass("class1")) {
        alert("class found");
    }
})
```

Comment: `$('.class:first')` returns a jQuery object containing the first `.class` element. `$('.class')[0]` returns the first `.class` element as a DOMElement. To fix your actual problem wrap the `this` reference in a jQuery object: `$(this).hasClass(...`

Comment: *"I **need** to use hasClass"* - do you?  why?  Your sample code can be :  `if ($(".class.class1").length > 0) alert("found");`  (or, if you prefer, `$(".class").filter(".class1").length`) - (removed last one, it was wrong)

Comment: Another difference is that if the selector does not match any elements, `$(".class:first")` will still be a jquery array (with length 0) while `$(".class")[0]` will be `undefined` (so may give errors if you try to use it without checking first)